# How do you create a python list comprehension of lambdas?

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension, deferred-execution

I am trying create a list of lambdas for deferred execution using a list comprehension.
The below is a simple example.

```
def func_a(message: str) -> None:
    print('a: ' + message)
    
def func_b(message: str) -> None:
    print('b: ' + message)

msg = 'some message'
funcs = [func_a, func_b]
funcs_w_args = [lambda : func(msg) for func in funcs]

for func in funcs_w_args:
    func()
```

The result is

```
b: some message
b: some message
```

Whereas the desired result should be

```
a: some message
b: some message
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: (hopefully can fit as a comment) I think you are running into name collision issues - the lambda says "lookup the function 'func' and run it". After the list comprehension, the name "func" -> func_b. Basically, func isn't closed until you actually run the lambda, so it's not giving what you expect. I am having trouble proving this (I thought func would have a value after the comprehension, but it doesn't) but i would bet it's something along those lines.

Comment: (which, actually, is exactly what @Carcigenicate 's linked question was showing, so go there for better examples :)

Comment: @Carcigenicate. Thanks for the link. It provides a thorough discussion of the topic. For a quick and direct answer However, I'd recommend CypherX's below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

What you are trying to achieve is defining `partial` functions (more generally). You can do this using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Here's how:

```py
from functools import partial

# Your Code
def func_a(message: str) -> None:
    print('a: ' + message)
    
def func_b(message: str) -> None:
    print('b: ' + message)

msg = 'some message'
funcs = [func_a, func_b]

# What I changed: a list of partially-defined functions
funcs_w_args = [partial(func, msg) for func in funcs]

# Now call partially defined functions
for func in funcs_w_args:
    func()
```

**Output**:

```sh
a: some message
b: some message
```

### Refernces

- Documentation for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: While I consider the question a duplicate, I thank you for placing a `functools.partial` solution here. `functools.partial` is ideal for the task and doesn't get nearly enough love. The traditional idiom abusing default arguments is just that - abusive, and only considered an idiom out of tradition. Unfortunately, these idioms have a **lot** of inertia (see also: `x[:]` used where `x.copy()` is appropriate).